# React Native and Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make a login/sign in  page that navigate to another page if the user enter the correct credentials using react native and Firebase . I enabled the authentication using email in the Firebase console, but I get an alert every time like in this image:

[image]

By searching in the internet, I found possible solutions like verifying that I'm using the right database in my app, but it didn't work. 
My code is here : https://github.com/haifaGh/AuthenticationFirebase

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you have done wrong, but few days ago i started firebase app for my own purpose, so you can check how have i done login and sign up.

https://github.com/dratwas/react-native-firebase-chat/pull/10/files

there is example in pr.

Comment: Thank you for your help .. I've just uploaded my code in this link https://github.com/haifaGh/AuthenticationFirebase and I didn't know where my error is ... Thank you